# Re-exporting ES6 modules giving weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, react-native, es6-modules

Context:
- React-Native (RN) project
- Started from RN 0.18, current RN version is 0.55.4
- Production application

I recently converted all our require() and module.exports to import/export (ES6 modules) since we were using both of them.

This mostly went fine but I am now noticing some weird behaviour when re-exporting things.

We have a stores/stores.js file that basically imports other stores and then re-exports them.

An example line from it:

```
export { default as ProjectStore } from './Project/ProjectStore';
```

So that I can do imports in files as following:

```
import { ProjectStore, OtherStore, OtherStore2 } from './Projects/Projects';
```

This is causing some weird unexpected behaviour where the Store is undefined for a while? causing a specific part of the app to crash.

On the other hand, when I import it normally it works fine:

```
import ProjectStore from './Project/ProjectStore';
```

I believe re-exporting is messing up how Babel solves cyclic dependencies? Or somewhere along those lines.

Comment: How ProjectStore is exported? Is it export default ProjectStore?

Comment: Yes, changing the order of import statements (and re-exports count as such) can change the order in which circular dependencies are resolved. Solution A: don't use circular dependencies, solution B: fix the order, solution C: don't use the import before it is initialised

Comment: If you need help with either solution, please post your original (working) module code as well as your current setup, of all the involved modules (with just the declarations and usages of the imports, not the full code)

Comment: @BhojendraNepal the problem is not about default/named import/exports. ProjectStore is exported default.

Comment: @Bergi I'm afraid I'm a bit limited into what I can show you due to company policy. Is there any tool I could use to draw up a diagram of some sort?

Comment: Please make an [mcve], it doesn't need to include any actual names or implementation, just show the module structure and dependencies.